# Import .p12 certificate to connect VPN in archlinux

Tags: certificate, vpn, archlinux

I need to connect to my company's VPN. The steps required to do that are;

1. install `cisco anyconnect secure mobility client`
2. import Developers Certicate (a .p12) certificate.
3. start `anyconnect client` and enter your username/password.

I've done the first and the third step. But except the .p12 certificate is not imported successfully, `anyconnect client` tells me that I have a `unauthorized connection mechanism`.

I have done the same steps in my windows machine. Windows provides a `certificate import wizard`. There I choose `local machine`, enter the password of the certificate and voila, the rest works.

In Linux, how do I import that file? Where should the file be?

I made my search but I could not came up with any valuable information.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

All it takes was to simply double click the certificate when Thunar the file manager was run from terminal with su priviliges. 
From the opened window, one must click 'import' button.